# SequelizeValidationError : askType cannot be an array or an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

I am working on React Project where I am targeting API for creating a records but in meantime I got this error `SequelizeValidationError : askType cannot be an array or an object` . I will share my code could someone please help me how to convert object value to single string . Thanks

**Code**

```
   let taskChange = function (value) {
        slotInfo.taskType = value;
    };

    <select name="taskType" onChange={taskChange}>
      <option value="no">Task Type</option>
      <option value="meeting">Meeting</option>
      <option value="followUp">Follow Up</option>
      <option value="viewing">Viewing</option>
      <option value="reminder">Reminder</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
```